# create infinite looping repeating file cat in linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, cat

What I'd like to do is send a single file "repeatedly" (like cat'ing it an infinite number of times) as input to another program.  Is there a way on the command line/using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) provides a mechanism by which bash can generate a temporary, readable filename connected to an arbitrary chunk of bash code for you:

```
./my_program -input <(while cat file_to_repeat; do :; done)
```

This will create a `/dev/fd/NN`-style name on operating systems that support it, or a named pipe otherwise.

Comment: If you want to send the input via stdin instead, write `< <(` instead of `<(`

Comment: @kangalioo, indeed. The OP conveyed out-of-band from the question that their program takes `-input` then a filename (by providing an answer showing a program requiring that usage mode), but the stdin approach is certainly more commmon.

Answer (score 10):

The [`yes` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/yes.1.html), using the file's contents as it's argument:

```
yes "$(<file)" | somecommand
```

Comment: A side effect of this approach is that any changes to the file are *not* picked up. It will continue to repeat the contents of the file as they were at the time it was first executed. Just in case this matters.

Comment: unfortunately, at least in OS X, with larger input files this yields ` /usr/bin/yes: Argument list too long`

Comment: ...also doesn't work (truncates content) if that file contains NULs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
while [ true ]; do cat somefile; done | somecommand
```

Comment: Should just be `while true;`. You don't need `[ ]`, that's for testing expressions.

Comment: The effect is the same, though. `[ true ]` succeeds because `[`'s argument is a non-empty string. `[ false ]` would work just as well, but I think everyone can agree that is unnecessarily confusing :)

Comment: The only draw I have with this approach (after trying it) is that if you try and send "stdin" to the `somecommand` (for instance, the `q` key to quit) it sometimes doesn't receive it, which, if needed to gracefully interrupt that command, makes it hard to exit...

Comment: @chepner, ...I'd call `while [ true ]` just as confusing, since it includes a false implication about the test program's behavior.

Comment: @rogerdpack, that's **always** true when a program's input is from a pipe (and it isn't directly polling for keyboard input from the TTY) -- nothing specific to this approach about it.

Comment: BTW, this has a serious bug: It tries to continue indefinitely, **even after the `cat` program has exited with a nonzero status**, thus even after `somecommand` has exited.

Answer (score 2):

Appears it is possible through the use of `mkfifo` (this way allows for easy control, restartability, and large files)

```
$ mkfifo eternally_looping_filename # you can name this what you want.
```

Then write to that fifo "[looping](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-cycle-loop-forever/)" from one bash prompt, ex: create script named bash_write_eternal.sh:

```
while [ true ]; do
  cat /path/to/file_want_repeated > ./eternally_looping_filename
done
```

run that in one terminal

```
$ ./bash_write_eternal.sh
```

(you could background it also if you want to reuse the same terminal)

then in another terminal, run your input program, like

```
$ ./my_program -input ./eternally_looping_filename
```

or

```
$ cat ./eternally_looping_filename | ./my_program
```

your program will now receive an eternal input of that file looping over and over.  You can even "pause" the receiving program by interrupting the terminal running the `bash_write_eternal.sh` script (its input will be suspended until you resume the fifo writing script).

Another benefit is "resumable" between invocations, and also if your program happens to not know how to receive input from "stdin" it can receive it from a filename here.

Comment: First, the idiom is `while true; do` or `while :; do`. Second, you don't need an named pipe for this. `while :; do cat /path/to/file/to/be/repeated; done | ./another-program` is enough. You may need an `-input -` to your other program, depending on how it's coded.

Comment: BTW, if you'd indicated in your question that your program accepted a `-input` parameter, you would have gotten an effective answer much more quickly.

Comment: `while cat /path/to/file/to/be/repeated; do :; done` would properly quit after the other side of the FIFO is closed. (As described in comments elsewhere, `while [ true ]` is misleading; even if you wanted that behavior, just use `while true`).

Answer (score 2):

A `while :` loop repeats forever:

```
while :
do cat input.txt
done | your-program
```

To use a helper function:

```
repeat() while :; do cat "$1"; done
repeat input.txt | your-program
```

Comment: ahh, but we don't really want *forever*; we want *until `your-program` exits*. That requires that we break the loop after `cat` fails.