# Create multiple files in Unix using a script

Tags: bash, unix, vim

I am new to unix and I am starting to get my head around it slowly. I would like to know how I can create multiple files within an folder in my directory. 
Untill now I was doing it manually one by one. I was using the following code:

```
echo 'random text here' > newfile1.txt
```

I would like to create a script that will do the following:

> new file x n
>
> newfile1.txt
>  newfile2.txt
>  newfile3.txt
>  newfilen.txt

I would like to have some dummy text inside the files to. I am learning vim and bash.

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034941/how-to-create-multiple-files-with-random-data-with-bash

Comment: What does Vim have to do with this question? Anything?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility:

```
for i in file{1..3}; do printf "random text\n" > $i; done
```

zsh also allows the more simpler:

```
printf "random text\n" > random_text{1..3}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
seq 3 | awk '{print "random text" > "newfile"i++".txt"}' i=1
```

In place of 3, put the value of n.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in `seq 1 10`; do
        echo "$3" > $1/$2$n.txt
done
```

This script takes in 3 command line arguments, the first is the already created folder you want the files created in, the second is the first part of the filename, the third is dummy text you want inserted. :)

./script.sh my_folder basename dummytext

(provided as a bash answer)

Answer (score 0):

A classic `for` loop would be good.
This is just for fun. (don't use in your script)

```
yes "foo text"|head -10|awk '{print >"newFile"NR".txt"}'
```

Sometimes we should use `yes` command, to show that we don't forget him, or he is gonna be sad. :-)

Comment: It's ok, `yes` is not going to be sad... @glenn-jackman found a brilliant use for him... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34556470/2836621   :-)